# How to display two buttons with Ajax on Submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, button

I have a Ajax Submit button which shows up with a message **Successfully Added. View Cart** when clicked on **Add to cart** button. Right now **Successfully Added**. and **View Cart** message is show as a single button. Is there any way to separate out Successfully Added and **View Cart** button?

**Add to cart button code:**

```
<fieldset class="add-to-cart-box">
    <legend><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></legend>
    <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
    <input name="qty" type="hidden" class="input-text qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" /></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <button class="form-button"  onclick="ajaxSubmit('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>', this)"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
</fieldset>
```

**Successfully Added. View Cart message and button code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxSubmit(url, button){
        var pars = '';
        var target = '';
        var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater(target,url, {method: 'get', parameters: pars});
        button.innerHTML = '<span>Successfully Added. View Cart</span>';
        button.className = 'form-button-alt';
        button.style.marginTop = '6px';
        button.attributes["onclick"].value = 'setLocation(\'/checkout/cart/\')';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are replacing the inner button html

```
 button.innerHTML = '<span>Successfully Added. View Cart</span>';
```

instead replace the button with two button instances

Comment: I want to display **Successfully Added**. and **View Cart** buttons separately. **View Cart** button will have hyperlink but not **Successfully Added** button. Thanks